# Create a mailbox in Outlook 2013 that reads eml files from folder

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2013, mailbox

How can I create a new mailbox in Outlook 2013 that reads `.eml` files from a specific folder on the network? I don't want to have to manually import each `.eml` file.

I don't want to send any e-mails from this mailbox. I would just like to view the messages in that folder. For some context, this relates to testing emails for development and QA. I would like to leverage some of the filtering/sorting that Outlook provides as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new PST Data File and import your EML files into this new PST.

To create a new PST data file, just use File -> Account Settings -> Data Files -> Add..

To import EML files, you can use the free [Import Messages from EML Files](https://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookMessagesImportEML/) utility. Advanced version allows you to import files periodically - it can move successfully imported files into the selected folder, thus avoiding duplicates to be created.

Comment: The OP knows *what* he wants to do; the question is ***how?***

Comment: How do I create a new PST Data File and import EML files into this new PST? If I did do that, would I have to import every time new files were created? I would prefer to have Outlook scan the directory for new files.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

To convert EML files to Outlook PST there is manual as well as expert solution. Both solutions have its own benefits and its own demerits. But i you want to convert EML to PST easily without creating any extra work for yourself try to convert EML files with some third-party tool like EML to PST Converter. If you wants to convert EML to PST manually you can check this out **GainTools EML to PST Converter**

Comment: You can simply download this tool and convert it.